# Angular data binding with reference types

Tags: angular, input, data-binding, reference, output

This is bugging me for some time now and I can't find direct answers to this.

Parent:

```
<app-table [array]="myarray"></app-text>
```

Child:

```
export class TableComponent {
    @Input()
    array: Element[] = [];
}
```

```
<p-dataTable [value]="array">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name">
        <ng-template let-record="rowData" pTemplate="body"> {{ record.name }} </ng-template>
    </p-column>

    <p-column field="value" header="Value" >
        <ng-template let-record="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                [(ngModel)]="record.value"
            />
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I'm sending a reference type object `myarray` from a parent to child `TableComponent` with the intention to modify the content of given object by the child. Everything works fine because we change values under the reference and no Output is required.

BUT

From the perspective of parent, the child only receives the data (`[ ]` and not `[( )]`) and one would expect that there should be no changes to the object. With value types there is no discussion, but what about reference types? Should I implement two way binding:

```
@Output()
arrayChange: EventEmitter<Element[]> = new EventEmitter<Element[]>();

emitChanges(): void {
    this.arrayChange.emit(this.value);
}
```

```
<app-table [(array)]="myarray"></app-text>
```

just to inform the parent about possible changes even when the reference stays the same? Or is it commonly expected in angular that reference types might change inside and two way binding should be implemented only when the actual reference changes?

Comment: what is your actual behavior problem here? can you explain in very short?

Comment: I'm wondering if developers expect by convention that values inside reference type object `myarray` might be modified by `app-table` if there is only one way data binding `<app-table [array]="myarray"></app-text>`, or if I should change my implementation. If I should change, then how would the correct implementation look like?

Comment: My opinion is that you should always take **immutability** into consideration whenever you develop a solution. It allows you to create more predictable code(among other benefits). In case of parent-child communication, I'd stick to  using `@Input()` and `@Output()` properties. This way, you can make your dumb components(i.e `app-table`) more efficient. Only the smart components(i.e `parent`) should dictate when the data is going to be mutated.

Comment: So two scenarios

1. Only Input of reference object

    a) I should clone object inside parent to ensure immutability and input the cloned one 

    b) I should clone object inside child and operate on the cloned one

2. Input of reference object with the purpose of modification

    a) I should clone object in parent and use `@Output` in child to emit changed object

    b) I should clone object in child and use `@Output` in child to emit changed object

    c) No cloning but still use `@Output` in child to emit changed object